# Outlook search bar options "from" change language automatically and stop working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, language

Everytime when searching for an email at the search bar using the option "from" (e.g. typing from:[email]), Outlook change the language of the word "from" to "de" (spanish translation), so then the option "from" stop working since only works when is in english.
[Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzov5.png)

Thanks,
Mario.

Comment: How is your issue going? Do above suggestion help to you?

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue only occur to a specific user?

Could the search feature work well in OWA?

Do your OS and outlook is in different languages?

- If yes, refer to the blog to [Switch between languages using the Language bar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
- If your OS and outlook is in the same language, here are some
  troubleshooting steps for your reference:

1. Run outlook in safe mode to check if there are any add-ins cause this issue.
2. Recreate outlook profile.
3. Use [Advanced Find](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-a-message-or-item-with-instant-search-69748862-5976-47b9-98e8-ed179f1b9e4d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to check if this issue continues.
4. upgrade outlook to the latest version.

In addition, here's a similar thread for your reference: [Outlook search properties does not work due to language problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-search-properties-does-not-work-due-to/82a09edf-9e0e-49ed-bec3-0101f8e9acb6)